# JQuery live click not working in IE with a tag

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag on my page that is added dynamically using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
```

I have the following jQuery within my `$(document).ready(function()`

```
 $("#ClickMe").live('click', function()
 {
     $("#SomeDiv1").show();
     $("#SomeDiv2").hide(); 
 });
```

This works fine in firefox, but not in IE.  I am developing in IE8 currently, but I will need it to run in IE7 minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by embeeding a call to a function in the anchor tag being rendered in the info window.

e.g.

```
> <a href="#" id="ClickMe" onclick="ClickMeFunc();">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: This really isn't a good answer, because you just hacked your way around the problem instead of actually solving it.

Comment: Thanks for constructive critisim.  I'll implement as you suggest... oh wait you didn't suggest anything... Thanks for the comment - not really that useful three months after I had the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem as you littlechris. Anchor tags in Google Maps infowindows would not accept jQuery live events in IE. Worked fine in FF, Chrome etc. Your workaround is great - cheers! And Nick - hacking around the problem *is* solving it sometimes. Having all the JS handlers outside the HTML is nice, but this is Google Maps we're using - it's nothing but JS!

Comment: Haha I just read over littlechris' reply and lol'd. I completely agree, sometimes you can't get at a solution and a workaround answers the question. Especially months later.

Answer (score 4):

The code probably is working just as it should, only it is not doing what you expect; as you are not doing anything from stopping the click event from causing browser navigation, that might disturb your showing and hiding of divs.

Try the following:

```
$('#ClickMe').live('click', function(ev) {
    $('#SomeDiv1').show();
    $('#SomeDiv2').hide();

    // Stop event handling in non-IE browsers:
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    // Stop event handling in IE
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have changed this.  But I put an alert in to see if the event is even firing, and no alert pops up.  It seems the live is not attachiong the event to the anchor in IE

Comment: When you add the link, do you do so by manually constructing it in jQuery or with the result of an AJAX call?

Comment: It is contained within a div that I then show using Google Maps Gmarker.openInfoWindowHtml(MyDiv).  This is run in the $.Ready function.

Comment: I can't find a method with that signature in the API reference - is your html added OK when you run it? Could you perhaps post a live example that we could test and experiment with?

Comment: Posted in original question :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the solution. I worked through the same issue, adding a 'click' to an 'a' tag that doesn't exist yet. Worked in FF but not in IE. The `a` tag had an `onclick` defined on it:

```
onclick="hideSubPage($('#formula-editor'));return false;"
```

I wanted to add an additional function to the 'click' (a particular refresh).

After hacking for a while, I removed the existing `onclick` from the `a` tag and everything worked, even in IE.

Basically in order for the `jquery.live()` to work in IE, it looks like the control that `jquery.live()` is targeting cannot have the the event already attached.

in page1 add click event to `a` tag.

```
$('#returnfromformulaeditor').live('click', function(ev) { hideSubPage($('#formula-editor'));  ev.preventDefault(); ev.stopPropagation(); refreshFormulaList();return false; });
```

in page 2 - the `a` tag before

```
<a href='#' id="returnfromformulaeditor" onclick="hideSubPage($('#formula-editor'));return false;" class="BackLink">&lt;&lt;Return </a>
```

in page 2 - the 'a' tag after

```
<a href='#' id="returnfromformulaeditor"  class="BackLink">&lt;&lt;Return </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because "Click" will bind the click event with the handler when Document is ready, but wont attach the same "click" event if any element is dynamically generated in dom. That is why we use "live".

Dude, if ".live" is not working in IE8, then go for ".delegate". I am using this and it is working fine in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [`click`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) event directly instead of [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) ?  You are binding to an element with an ID, so I presume that you won't have other elements added later on with the same ID; and that defeats the purpose of using the `live` function.

---

Try it like this :

```
$("#ClickMe").click(function()
 {
     $("#SomeDiv1").show();
     $("#SomeDiv2").hide(); 
 });
```

Comment: I should have stated the anchoir tag is added dynamically to the page.